# Jquery, meteorjs, editabletext package

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

My question is how to with jquery make when I click edit button that editabletext field comes into focus. Here is my code

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $('#editingTask').focus();
});

<ul>
    {{#each tasksToDo}}
        {{>task}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>


<template name="task">
  <li class="list_item">
    <span id="editingTask">{{> editableText collection="tasks" field="title"}}</span>
    <br>
    <div class="editBt">
        <button class="completed">Completed</button>
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</tempate>
```

Comment: the current click event is not working?

Comment: jup this doesn't work... it won't focus on euditabletext text area

Comment: try with a Meteor event handler

`Template.task.events({
 'click #editingTask' : function(event, template){
   $('#editingTask').focus();
 }
})`

Comment: I just found the trigger widget... sry about that, didn't look but it still doesn't give I put the ".editable-text-trigger" on edit button but it won't activate... and i don't have idea how to connect them... maybe by default hold span on click false and if pressed it becomes true, but it still doesn't give me desired solution